# Single Instance Window WPF not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I only want to have a single instance of my Window in WPF.

My code in the window:

```
public static bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsOpen = true;
}

private void Window_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsOpen = false;
}
```

My code in the open function

```
if (MyWindow!= null)
{
    if (MyWindowName.IsOpen)
    {
        MyWindow.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        MyWindow.Close();
        MyWindow= null;
    }
}
if (MyWindow!= null) return;

MyWindow= new MyWindowName();
MyWindow.Show();
MyWindow.Activate();
```

But I am able  to open many instances of the window if I click fast 3-5 times.

Thanks

Comment: you don't need `IsOpen` property as [`Window.IsLoaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded.aspx) will give you exactly the same result

Comment: go with singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a delay between you opening with window with the show command (which will then process the message queue allowing the processing of the other clicks) and then the firing of the windows loaded event.

An extremely quick and dirty fix would be to move the IsOpen assignment to just before the show command, you could also use a return inside the if to remove the need for a second check.

```
if (MyWindow!= null)
{
    if (MyWindowName.IsOpen)
    {
        MyWindow.Activate();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        MyWindow.Close();
        MyWindow= null;
    }
}

MyWindow= new MyWindowName();
MyWindow.IsOpen = true;
MyWindow.Show();
MyWindow.Activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're hitting a race condition. It's not that surprising considering you're having to leverage the event model of the `Window`. Just declare an `object` in the same class `MyWindow` is declared in, like this:

```
private object _lockObj = new object();
```

and then when doing your work, do this:

```
lock (_lockObj)
{
    if (MyWindow!= null)
    {
        if (MyWindowName.IsOpen)
        {
            MyWindow.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            MyWindow.Close();
            MyWindow= null;
        }
    }
    if (MyWindow!= null) return;

    MyWindow= new MyWindowName();
    MyWindow.Show();
    MyWindow.Activate();
}
```

Comment: That won't necessarily work.  MyWindow.Show() will return quickly and you could still exit the lock before the window loaded event fires.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple code.

```
  Window2 win;
        object locker = new Object();
        private void OnShow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (win == null)
                    win = new Window2();
                win.Show();
            }
        }

        private void OnHide(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (win != null)
                win.Hide();
        }
```